# UWP:- App's StreamSocket.InputStream.ReadAsync blocks when I create an answer (via Mixed reality webrtc) for a remote offer

Tags: sockets, uwp, webrtc, windows-mixed-reality

I've a UWP app which connects to a remote host to receive remote offer/answer messages
related to audio video calls. I'm using mixed reality webrtc 2.0.2 for creating peer connection/setting remote descriptions/creating answer-offer etc.

How stream socket is created?

```
    var hostName = new Windows.Networking.HostName(host);
    if(_sslStream == null)
        _sslStream = new StreamSocket();
    _sslStream.Control.KeepAlive = true;
    try
    {
        _sslStream.ConnectAsync(hostName, port.ToString(), SocketProtectionLevel.Tls12).AsTask().Wait();                        
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.printStackTrace(e);
    }
```

and this is how I'm reading the data from the input stream of streamSocket

```
    private byte ReadByte()
    {
        try
        {
            IBuffer buffer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer(1);
            _sslStream.InputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 1, InputStreamOptions.Partial).AsTask().Wait();
            return buffer.GetByte(0);
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            throw new WmsCommunicationException("IOException on readBYte");
        }
        catch (WmsCommunicationException wce)
        {
            throw wce;
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException e1)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

When I get a remote offer message (with 40+ mlines in it like the one below) in it, I create an answer in the peer connection.
The moment I make a call to PeerConnection.CreateAnswer(), _sslStream.InputStream.ReadAsync() is blocking and not allowing any new messages to be received. But if I create an answer for a remote offer that has 5-6 mlines in it, it works fine and there is no blocking on the stream socket.

Any pointers on why is it blocking?

```
v=0
o=- 1312117488 1499418450 IN IP4 100.197.191.345
s=-
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
t=0 0
a=ice-lite
a=fingerprint:sha-256 FA:33:7C:F0:90:A9:42:83:5A:4C:10:DA:57:73:A7:FF:A6:8D:02:9E:96:0A:F8:D5:7B:75:55:E2:AA:24:EB:1A
a=setup:actpass
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 100 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 
a=rtcp:443
a=sendonly
a=ice-ufrag:dKopXYaIkDgUiWBh
a=ice-pwd:Mw11h23nCQ7hYK5I4cyBST
a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2130706431 100.197.191.345 443 typ host
a=candidate:0 2 UDP 2130706430 100.197.191.345 443 typ host
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:0
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:52503 cname:t8IruIpXPB_0
a=ssrc:52503 msid:t8IruIpXPB_0
a=ssrc:52503 mslabel:t8IruIpXPB_0
a=ssrc:52503 label:t8IruIpXPB_0
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:1
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:102504 cname:OeBDZE7qkF_1
a=ssrc:102504 msid:OeBDZE7qkF_1
a=ssrc:102504 mslabel:OeBDZE7qkF_1
a=ssrc:102504 label:OeBDZE7qkF_1
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:2
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:1002506 cname:YV40PVvyXV_2
a=ssrc:1002506 msid:YV40PVvyXV_2
a=ssrc:1002506 mslabel:YV40PVvyXV_2
a=ssrc:1002506 label:YV40PVvyXV_2
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:3
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:202509 cname:eSbPtrKfma_3
a=ssrc:202509 msid:eSbPtrKfma_3
a=ssrc:202509 mslabel:eSbPtrKfma_3
a=ssrc:202509 label:eSbPtrKfma_3
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:4
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:345513 cname:uj9aRhTmlX_4
a=ssrc:345513 msid:uj9aRhTmlX_4
a=ssrc:345513 mslabel:uj9aRhTmlX_4
a=ssrc:345513 label:uj9aRhTmlX_4
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:5
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:302518 cname:bnnpQXJQpM_5
a=ssrc:302518 msid:bnnpQXJQpM_5
a=ssrc:302518 mslabel:bnnpQXJQpM_5
a=ssrc:302518 label:bnnpQXJQpM_5
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:6
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:353454 cname:mo7dh6yH5Q_6
a=ssrc:353454 msid:mo7dh6yH5Q_6
a=ssrc:353454 mslabel:mo7dh6yH5Q_6
a=ssrc:353454 label:mo7dh6yH5Q_6
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:7
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:402531 cname:5rJ8R66L0L_7
a=ssrc:402531 msid:5rJ8R66L0L_7
a=ssrc:402531 mslabel:5rJ8R66L0L_7
a=ssrc:402531 label:5rJ8R66L0L_7
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:8
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:452539 cname:mFluFTcXgd_8
a=ssrc:452539 msid:mFluFTcXgd_8
a=ssrc:452539 mslabel:mFluFTcXgd_8
a=ssrc:452539 label:mFluFTcXgd_8
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:9
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:502548 cname:gUf902oDbo_9
a=ssrc:502548 msid:gUf902oDbo_9
a=ssrc:502548 mslabel:gUf902oDbo_9
a=ssrc:502548 label:gUf902oDbo_9
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:10
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:552558 cname:R6ts1Mhr5N_10
a=ssrc:552558 msid:R6ts1Mhr5N_10
a=ssrc:552558 mslabel:R6ts1Mhr5N_10
a=ssrc:552558 label:R6ts1Mhr5N_10
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:11
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:602569 cname:YbSvUd74J6_11
a=ssrc:602569 msid:YbSvUd74J6_11
a=ssrc:602569 mslabel:YbSvUd74J6_11
a=ssrc:602569 label:YbSvUd74J6_11
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:12
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:652581 cname:ZO3zk86gp9_12
a=ssrc:652581 msid:ZO3zk86gp9_12
a=ssrc:652581 mslabel:ZO3zk86gp9_12
a=ssrc:652581 label:ZO3zk86gp9_12
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:13
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:702594 cname:jgLl5lWT79_13
a=ssrc:702594 msid:jgLl5lWT79_13
a=ssrc:702594 mslabel:jgLl5lWT79_13
a=ssrc:702594 label:jgLl5lWT79_13
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:14
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:752608 cname:72rUDbAvK7_14
a=ssrc:752608 msid:72rUDbAvK7_14
a=ssrc:752608 mslabel:72rUDbAvK7_14
a=ssrc:752608 label:72rUDbAvK7_14
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:100
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:802623 cname:mrULgkLPrx_100
a=ssrc:802623 msid:mrULgkLPrx_100
a=ssrc:802623 mslabel:mrULgkLPrx_100
a=ssrc:802623 label:mrULgkLPrx_100
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:16
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:852639 cname:dhBrAJKkSs_16
a=ssrc:852639 msid:dhBrAJKkSs_16
a=ssrc:852639 mslabel:dhBrAJKkSs_16
a=ssrc:852639 label:dhBrAJKkSs_16
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:17
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:902656 cname:H60IQio23X_17
a=ssrc:902656 msid:H60IQio23X_17
a=ssrc:902656 mslabel:H60IQio23X_17
a=ssrc:902656 label:H60IQio23X_17
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:18
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:952674 cname:40gSk57ocZ_18
a=ssrc:952674 msid:40gSk57ocZ_18
a=ssrc:952674 mslabel:40gSk57ocZ_18
a=ssrc:952674 label:40gSk57ocZ_18
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:19
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:1002693 cname:MBFIKD8CrH_19
a=ssrc:1002693 msid:MBFIKD8CrH_19
a=ssrc:1002693 mslabel:MBFIKD8CrH_19
a=ssrc:1002693 label:MBFIKD8CrH_19
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:20
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:1052713 cname:7CfW1FemXq_20
a=ssrc:1052713 msid:7CfW1FemXq_20
a=ssrc:1052713 mslabel:7CfW1FemXq_20
a=ssrc:1052713 label:7CfW1FemXq_20
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:21
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:1102734 cname:kalZN86F7i_21
a=ssrc:1102734 msid:kalZN86F7i_21
a=ssrc:1102734 mslabel:kalZN86F7i_21
a=ssrc:1102734 label:kalZN86F7i_21
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:22
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:11002756 cname:VPBURyhqFn_22
a=ssrc:11002756 msid:VPBURyhqFn_22
a=ssrc:11002756 mslabel:VPBURyhqFn_22
a=ssrc:11002756 label:VPBURyhqFn_22
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:23
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:1202779 cname:uXaoLUfxCx_23
a=ssrc:1202779 msid:uXaoLUfxCx_23
a=ssrc:1202779 mslabel:uXaoLUfxCx_23
a=ssrc:1202779 label:uXaoLUfxCx_23
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:24
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:1345803 cname:xazhStQ7Y7_24
a=ssrc:1345803 msid:xazhStQ7Y7_24
a=ssrc:1345803 mslabel:xazhStQ7Y7_24
a=ssrc:1345803 label:xazhStQ7Y7_24
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:25
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:1302828 cname:T7ektAx0ha_25
a=ssrc:1302828 msid:T7ektAx0ha_25
a=ssrc:1302828 mslabel:T7ektAx0ha_25
a=ssrc:1302828 label:T7ektAx0ha_25
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:26
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:1352854 cname:bcXjb9Meei_26
a=ssrc:1352854 msid:bcXjb9Meei_26
a=ssrc:1352854 mslabel:bcXjb9Meei_26
a=ssrc:1352854 label:bcXjb9Meei_26
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:27
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:1402881 cname:jzkl3HD0gv_27
a=ssrc:1402881 msid:jzkl3HD0gv_27
a=ssrc:1402881 mslabel:jzkl3HD0gv_27
a=ssrc:1402881 label:jzkl3HD0gv_27
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:28
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:1452909 cname:gkcKgTJqRi_28
a=ssrc:1452909 msid:gkcKgTJqRi_28
a=ssrc:1452909 mslabel:gkcKgTJqRi_28
a=ssrc:1452909 label:gkcKgTJqRi_28
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:29
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:10002938 cname:yDojdlSSDp_29
a=ssrc:10002938 msid:yDojdlSSDp_29
a=ssrc:10002938 mslabel:yDojdlSSDp_29
a=ssrc:10002938 label:yDojdlSSDp_29
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:30
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:10052968 cname:F1MWuis8dB_30
a=ssrc:10052968 msid:F1MWuis8dB_30
a=ssrc:10052968 mslabel:F1MWuis8dB_30
a=ssrc:10052968 label:F1MWuis8dB_30
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:31
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:1602999 cname:KvORjxSa7m_31
a=ssrc:1602999 msid:KvORjxSa7m_31
a=ssrc:1602999 mslabel:KvORjxSa7m_31
a=ssrc:1602999 label:KvORjxSa7m_31
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:32
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:1653031 cname:oJWkApZUtW_32
a=ssrc:1653031 msid:oJWkApZUtW_32
a=ssrc:1653031 mslabel:oJWkApZUtW_32
a=ssrc:1653031 label:oJWkApZUtW_32
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:33
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:1703064 cname:S5zJqc5Vh0_33
a=ssrc:1703064 msid:S5zJqc5Vh0_33
a=ssrc:1703064 mslabel:S5zJqc5Vh0_33
a=ssrc:1703064 label:S5zJqc5Vh0_33
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:34
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:1753098 cname:WgMW5Sv6Nc_34
a=ssrc:1753098 msid:WgMW5Sv6Nc_34
a=ssrc:1753098 mslabel:WgMW5Sv6Nc_34
a=ssrc:1753098 label:WgMW5Sv6Nc_34
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:35
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:1803133 cname:44k94RUjmn_35
a=ssrc:1803133 msid:44k94RUjmn_35
a=ssrc:1803133 mslabel:44k94RUjmn_35
a=ssrc:1803133 label:44k94RUjmn_35
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:36
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:1853169 cname:65XUyM0Qt9_36
a=ssrc:1853169 msid:65XUyM0Qt9_36
a=ssrc:1853169 mslabel:65XUyM0Qt9_36
a=ssrc:1853169 label:65XUyM0Qt9_36
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:37
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:1903206 cname:FMdRWAEdTu_37
a=ssrc:1903206 msid:FMdRWAEdTu_37
a=ssrc:1903206 mslabel:FMdRWAEdTu_37
a=ssrc:1903206 label:FMdRWAEdTu_37
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:38
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:1953244 cname:aKWPVx4AVR_38
a=ssrc:1953244 msid:aKWPVx4AVR_38
a=ssrc:1953244 mslabel:aKWPVx4AVR_38
a=ssrc:1953244 label:aKWPVx4AVR_38
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:39
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:2003283 cname:h4aA9QofTc_39
a=ssrc:2003283 msid:h4aA9QofTc_39
a=ssrc:2003283 mslabel:h4aA9QofTc_39
a=ssrc:2003283 label:h4aA9QofTc_39
m=video 443 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
c=IN IP4 100.197.191.345
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=mid:40
a=rtcp-mux
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=ssrc:2053323 cname:1KhTc2oFOH_40
a=ssrc:2053323 msid:1KhTc2oFOH_40
a=ssrc:2053323 mslabel:1KhTc2oFOH_40
a=ssrc:2053323 label:1KhTc2oFOH_40
```

Answer (score 0):

> App's StreamSocket.InputStream.ReadAsync blocks when I create an

The problem is your asynchronous method is called synchronously, you should use await keyword to repalce `task.AsTask().Wait()`

```
await _sslStream.InputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 1, InputStreamOptions.Partial);
```

For more please refer to [Threading and async programming document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/). and this is offical [streamsocket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/streamsocket/) sample that you could refer to.

Comment: I changed the implementation to async/await and still the StreamSocket.InputStream.ReadAsync blocks

Comment: Can you share [mcve]?